# CodeIgniter Upload Class min_width & min_height

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing, upload

is there a working solution to add min_width & min_height in the Upload class in libraries/Uploads.php ?

Only what I've found is this 
[How to set minimum upload size in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354138/how-to-set-minimum-upload-size-in-codeigniter)

but it's not working. I don't have any ideas to figure it out.

What I need is an image with fix width and height (in this case 2500x900px).

Answer (score 0):

Found a helper function **[here](https://www.developphp.com/video/PHP/Image-Resize-Function-Tutorial-jpg-gif-png-Change-Size)**.

**View:**

```
<form action="/xyz/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    Choose your file here:
    <input name="uploaded_file" type="file"/><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload It"/>
</form>
```

**Image helper** *(application/helpers/image_helper.php)*:

```
<?php
// Function for resizing jpg, gif, or png image files
function ak_img_resize($target, $newcopy, $w, $h, $ext) {
    list($w_orig, $h_orig) = getimagesize($target);
    $scale_ratio = $w_orig / $h_orig;
    if (($w / $h) > $scale_ratio) {
           $w = $h * $scale_ratio;
    } else {
           $h = $w / $scale_ratio;
    }
    $img = "";
    $ext = strtolower($ext);
    if ($ext == "gif"){ 
      $img = imagecreatefromgif($target);
    } else if($ext =="png"){ 
      $img = imagecreatefrompng($target);
    } else { 
      $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
    }
    $tci = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
    // imagecopyresampled(dst_img, src_img, dst_x, dst_y, src_x, src_y, dst_w, dst_h, src_w, src_h)
    imagecopyresampled($tci, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w_orig, $h_orig);
    imagejpeg($tci, $newcopy, 80);
}
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php
class Xyz extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('image');
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        // Access the $_FILES global variable for this specific file being uploaded
        // and create local PHP variables from the $_FILES array of information
        $fileName = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]; // The file name
        $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
        $fileType = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
        $fileSize = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
        $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
        $kaboom = explode(".", $fileName); // Split file name into an array using the dot
        $fileExt = end($kaboom); // Now target the last array element to get the file extension
        // START PHP Image Upload Error Handling --------------------------------------------------
        if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
            echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
            exit();
        } else if($fileSize > 5242880) { // if file size is larger than 5 Megabytes
            echo "ERROR: Your file was larger than 5 Megabytes in size.";
            unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
            exit();
        } else if (!preg_match("/.(gif|jpg|png)$/i", $fileName) ) {
             // This condition is only if you wish to allow uploading of specific file types    
             echo "ERROR: Your image was not .gif, .jpg, or .png.";
             unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
             exit();
        } else if ($fileErrorMsg == 1) { // if file upload error key is equal to 1
            echo "ERROR: An error occured while processing the file. Try again.";
            exit();
        }
        // END PHP Image Upload Error Handling ----------------------------------------------------
        // Place it into your "uploads" folder mow using the move_uploaded_file() function
        $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "uploads/$fileName");
        // Check to make sure the move result is true before continuing
        if ($moveResult != true) {
            echo "ERROR: File not uploaded. Try again.";
            unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
            exit();
        }
        unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder

        $target_file = "uploads/$fileName";
        $resized_file = "uploads/resized_$fileName";
        $wmax = 2500;
        $hmax = 900;
        ak_img_resize($target_file, $resized_file, $wmax, $hmax, $fileExt);
        // ----------- End Universal Image Resizing Function -----------
        // Display things to the page so you can see what is happening for testing purposes
        echo "The file named <strong>$fileName</strong> uploaded successfuly.<br /><br />";
        echo "It is <strong>$fileSize</strong> bytes in size.<br /><br />";
        echo "It is an <strong>$fileType</strong> type of file.<br /><br />";
        echo "The file extension is <strong>$fileExt</strong><br /><br />";
        echo "The Error Message output for this upload is: $fileErrorMsg";
    }
}
```